# Assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast warning

Tags: c, pointers, casting, variable-assignment

Can anybody explain why the following code gives the following warning and how to remedy it?

```
warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

Here is the code:

```
int tcp_socket(void)
{
    int s;

    if ((s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        _logf(LOG_DEBUG, "LOG %s:%d (%s) - %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, "Error creating socket");
        return -1;
    }
    return s;       
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int socket;
    socket = tcp_socket;
    if(socket == -1) {
        _logf(LOG_INFO, "LOG %s:%d (%s) - %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, "Error creating socket, exiting...");
        exit(-1);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Correct this:

`socket = tcp_socket;`

to

`socket = tcp_socket();`

`tcp_socket()` is a function call, while `tcp_socket` is a pointer to the function location in memory.

Comment: @Tomcelic : Based on your **reputation**, I think either you were in hurry, or frustrated (of long hours of coding) to do this kind of mistake. :-)

Comment: I'm actually newish to C, she is a cold and cruel mistress !

Comment: @Tomcelic Be patient with her and one day she will take you to the wonderland :)